# c++ temp object created?

Tags: c++, object, constructor, function-call

I would like to know how this code works.

```
class Room
{
    int sqft;
public:
    Room(int k)
    {
        sqft = k;
    }
    int add(Room r)
    {
        return r.sqft + sqft;
    }
};
int main()
{
    Room living = Room(400);
    Room Kitchen = Room(250);
    Room Bedroom = Room(300);
    int total = living.add(Kitchen.add(Bedroom)); // ***
    cout << total << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The starred line is calling the add function within the Room class. But after Kitchen.add(Bedroom) the returned type is an int. There is not an add function that would take an int as a parameter so I expected the code to error. I thought the line would need to be:

```
int total = living.add(Room(Kitchen.add(Bedroom)));
```

And this indeed works as well, I just don't understand how it works just passing the int to add as this line works as well:

```
cout << living.add(10);
```

It appears as though since Room takes an int constructor c++ then knows how to implicitly cast an int to a Room. Is this true? And what is going on in C++ behind the scenes that makes this work?

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's true, since you declared a constructor that takes an `int` parameter, the compiler will implicitly convert an `int` to a `Room`.

You fix this by declaring the constructor to be explicit, then the compiler will no longer do an implicit conversion but will require you to *explicitly* call the constructor as you do in your example.

```
  explicit Room(int k)
//^^^^^^^^
{
    sqft = k;
}

Room Bedroom = Room(300);                       // still works
int total = living.add(Kitchen.add(Bedroom));   // gives compile error
total = living.add(Room(Kitchen.add(Bedroom))); // works
```

Comment: It would seem like c++ would incur a large performance hit if it has to check all the constructors for Room (thinking of inherited ones as well) to see if it can convert this to anything acceptable for the call. Does marking it explicit then save that performance hit?

Comment: @JayLaughlin there's no performance hit, identifying the correct constructor call occurs at compile time, not run time.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
 int total = living.add(Kitchen.add(Bedroom));
```

can be broken down to execute this first

```
 Kitchen.add(Bedroom)
```

Here we return an `int`. The compiler then looks for a `Room`. It then scratches its head and think - I know I can create a `Room` from an `int` by using a constructor. It then goes away and does this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Constructor Room(int x) is defined. That means when you are calling a method that has a Room argument,but calling it instead with an int, than
the compiler automatically converts the int by calling the constructor Room(your_int_argument),thus creating a suitable room object for the function call. It's called implicit conversion.